# List available capture formats

Tags: c, video-capture, mjpeg, v4l2

New to V4L, I decided to start using the video4linux2 library in order to capture a frame from my camera in C (I am using the uvcvideo module with a Ricoh Co. camera). I followed several guides and tutorials, and managed to get a running program. My question is mainly about this usual code line :

```
struct v4l2_format format = {0};
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
// ...
```

This is where I set the actual video format to use when capturing. As you can see, in this sample, I'm using MJPEG (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h#L390). Even though this might be a great format and all, my application will probably require simple RGB formatting, pixel per pixel I guess. For this reason, I tried using RGB format constants such as `V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24`. Now for some reason... v4l2 doesn't like it. I'm guessing this is hardware-related, but I'd like to avoid MJPEG manipulations as much as possible. For testing purposes, I tried using other constants and formats, but no matter what I did, v4l2 kept changing the `pixelformat` field's value :

```
xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &format); // This call succeeds with errno != EINTR.
if(format.fmt.pix.pixelformat != V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB24){
    // My program always enters this block when not using MJPEG.
    fprintf(stderr, "Format wasn't accepted by v4l2.");
    exit(4);
}
```

Now my question is : is there a way I could get a list of accepted video formats (and I mean, accepted by my camera/v4l2), from which I could pick something else than MJPEG ? If you think I have to stick with MJPEG, would you recommend me any library allowing me to manipulate it, and eventually, to draw back the capture in a GUI frame ?

### Barbarian test code

I used the following trick to test all available formats on my hardware. First, some shell script to get a list of all formats...

```
grep 'V4L2_PIX_FMT' /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h | grep define | tr '\t' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed 's/$/,/g'
```

... the output of which is used in this C program :

```
int formats[] = {/* result of above command */};
int i = 0;
struct v4l2_format format = {0};

for(i = 0; i < /* number of lines in previous command output */; i++){
    format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    format.fmt.pix.width = 320;
    format.fmt.pix.height = 240;
    format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = formats[i];
    format.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;
    if(xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &format) != -1 && format.fmt.pix.pixelformat == formats[i])
        fprintf(stderr, "Accepted : %d\n", i);
}
```

This test reveals that only `V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV` and `V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG` are functional. Any way I could improve this, or is it hardware-related ?

Comment: http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/pixfmt.html ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, my fault. I am looking for a list of available and **accepted** formats, meaning formats my camera would accept to use (see my `if` statement above). When I set something else that MJPEG, the `pixelformat` attribute is unset by the library, probably because it cannot be handled by my hardware.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Linux, command line utility **v4l2-ctl** displays all of a webcam's natively supported formats -- install it with `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`, run it with `v4l2-ctl -dX --list-formats-ext`  where `X` is the camera index as in `/dev/videoX`. These formats are reported to the `v4l2` kernel module via `uvcvideo` module and they are supported natively by the webcam chipset. Only the listed formats are supported by `v4l2`, anything else would need to be coded by the user, and RGBs are *very* seldom provided, despite virtually all CCDs working in Bayer RGGB. The most common formats by far are YUV422 (YUYV or [YUY2](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#YUY2)) and MJPEG, with a certain overlap: MJPEG achieve larger frame rates for large resolutions.

C++ code for listing the camera formats can be found in Chromium GetDeviceSupportedFormats() implementation for Linux [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/media/video/capture/linux/video_capture_device_linux.cc&q=getdevicesupportedformats&sq=package%3achromium&l=144).

If you have to plug code to convert YUV to RGB I'd recommend [libyuv](https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/) which has been optimized for plenty of architectures.

Comment: Nothing else to say, perfect answer : the `VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT` call was what I needed, and `v4l2-ctl` uses it :) Thank you! libyuv will probably help me as I litteraly failed all my attempts to convert mathematically. By getting RGB values, I'll be able to draw the frame back using the SDL (and maybe I should have a look at YUV overlays...). Do you know of any library allowing me to draw back MJPEG-encoded frames ?

Comment: If you want to convert MJPEG them to RGB, `libyuv` supports this conversion as well as just another color space (pixelformat, to be more concrete), see f.e. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libyuv/include/libyuv/video_common.h&sq=package:chromium&rcl=1395577886&l=85 .

Comment: Does `libyuv` provide C bindings ? The program I'm working on isn't built in C++.

Comment: Both C and C++ should work, see https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/source/browse/trunk/include/libyuv/convert.h#22

Answer (score 6):

In order to enumerate the available format you can use ioctl [VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-old/vidioc-enum-fmt.html)

To print descriptions of capture format supported by `/dev/video0` you can process like this :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = v4l2_open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        struct v4l2_fmtdesc fmtdesc;
        memset(&fmtdesc,0,sizeof(fmtdesc));
        fmtdesc.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        while (ioctl(fd,VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT,&fmtdesc) == 0)
        {    
            printf("%s\n", fmtdesc.description);
            fmtdesc.index++;
        }
        v4l2_close(fd);
    }
}
```